# How could I store gps coordinates to make it easy to find which ones are close to eachother?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, gps

Say you have a list of gps coordinates for every restaurant on earth, and you have the coordinates for your current location. You want to find the closest n restaurants. Obviously it could take forever to search through an unsorted list, they need to be indexed somehow.

How should they be stored/indexed to be able to find the closest ones easily? I was thinking some kind of a double dictionary by latitude and longtitude or a double hash of some kind, but I'm sure this problem has been tackled before, and I'm wondering if there's an "optimal" solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe a KD-Tree is the general approach to these queries.

[Wikipedia entry on KD-Tree.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)

[Nearest neighbor search info on Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search)

[Previous question on SO about NNS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639755/best-performance-critical-algorithm-for-solving-nearest-neighbor/1639920#1639920)

Implementations:

[PCL](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/kdtree_search.php)

[KdTree in Java](https://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/KdTree.java)

Comment: That looks promising, although I'm wondering if there wouldn't be a better way to do it for gps, seeing as the locations wouldn't be distributed throughout a 3d space, but on the 2d surface of a sphere. Thoughts?

Comment: @NathanTempelman Well, from what I know about KD-Trees, they perform better with less dimensions. But I am not expect in the NNS space, so there may be better data-structures.

Comment: @NathanTempelman I've added a new link to a previous NNS question on SO.

Comment: Given the sparsity of restaurants in high latitudes, using a 2D kd-tree to represent those parts of the surface of the Earth of practical interest is a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a quadtree, especially a quadkey. It can be very efficient because you can change the gridsize. There are also many different quadkeys, for example morton curve, hilbert curve, h-tree, moore curve.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a KDTree implementation in Java or Android, see my answer to a similar SO-question [following this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218081/how-to-calculate-distance-from-different-markers-in-a-map-and-then-pick-up-the-l/19390750#19390750).
I posted also a 2D implementation in the same SO question, but this may return wrong results, if the points are distributed across a great range of latitudes. (An absolute distance in longitude degrees translates into a whole range of possible east-west distance in meters depending on the latitude).
I am still using the 2D-algorithm, as I am only interested in waypoints in less than 1000 meter distance. And there the 2D version worked fine so far.